# How do I save iCloud photos to external hard drive?

Tags: icloud, hard-drive

Photos on my iPad are backed up on iCloud, but as my iCloud storage is full I want to back up my iCloud photos to an external hard drive. How do I do this on my Windows desktop PC? I do not have a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Sign in to https://www.icloud.com and download/ export your photos from the web app.

Comment: How do you do this? The web app only allows selected photos to be downloaded, and I can't see how to select all photos.

Comment: (I'd upvote this, but don't have the rep.) I used an iPhone for a while, and now my photos are in iCloud. I've tried signing in to my account using Chrome, and I can see my photos, but none of the UI elements work. I then borrowed a Windows machine and tried using IE, but as soon as I clicked on anything, everything blanked out, and I am looking at a white page. I don't know if Apple lacks the competence to develop a simple web page, or if they are deliberately sabotaging users and holding their data hostage to get them back into their expensive walled garden..

Comment: ...but so far, it looks like the only option is to get your hands on some Apple-certified equipement, and look for a way to transfer stuff out from under Apple's control. Also tried firefox - works the same (i.e., it doesn't) as with Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I use an app called Photos to Disk http://www.photos-to-disk.com/

It's really easy to use and it has automatic folder organization options

Comment: The OP is looking for a Windows app, as they do not have a Mac